# How does false != X in PHP work?

Tags: php

Is the `$ligne` a reserved variable of some kind? What does `@mysql_fetch_array` really do?

```
$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE username ='".$username."'");

if (false != ($ligne = @mysql_fetch_array ($resultat))) {
    $er.='This username ('.$username.') is already taken.';
}
```

I am trying to understand how this block of code works. This is what I gather so far:

1. The variable `$resultat` is an array of elements returned from the query output. If the query has nothing to return then `$resultat` will be an array with 0 elements?
2. `@mysql_fetch_array` returns each row of `$resultat`. Is this correct?
3. I am lost after this ... is $ligne a special kind of variable that holds all output of `@mysql_fetch_array`?
4. How does `false!=` work?

I get the general idea of the idea what this code block does i.e. to return a message that a username is already taken, but I am not sure how it goes implementing it.

Comment: Just the way someone has written the code. `$ligne` can be changed to whatever you want - it's just a variable holding the result array set.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` gives back `FALSE` if no resource is present. That means that it will be `FALSE` if no results were found. It's a lousy alternative to not count rows. So it's simply saying; *If there are results found, show this message*, because `FALSE is NOT equal to FALSE is FALSE`.

Comment: As no one has said this yet, I want to point out that `mysql_` functions are deprecated.  You should start using `PDO` or `mySQLi` a soon as you possibly can.

Comment: The reversed-style syntax is sometimes known as a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a french code...
All mysql_* functions are deprecated, PDO is recommended.

1. Read doc about mysql_query()
   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
   mysql_query() does not return an array but a resource, when there is no result, processing this resource will return to you an empty result. Read 2.
2. Read doc about mysql_fetch_array()
   This function returns the next row or false if there are no more row.
   @ prevents all PHP error reports for this function call.
3. $ligne is an array containing the row's columns, if you have an ID column in your table and if your query request it, you will get an 'ID' key in this array, with the associated value obviously.
4. Compare the result to false (in PHP, 0, null, an empty string, '0' are considered as false). Comparing a result to false by this way is really "stupid", but it's a common mistake.

This code could be simplier and more efficient...

```
$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM temp_users WHERE username LIKE '".$username."' LIMIT 1") or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
if( mysql_num_rows($resultat) ) {
    $er.='This username ('.$username.') is already taken.';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. No, `$resultat` is not an array. It's a *resource* that provides access to the results of the query, or `false` if an error occurred when performing the query.
2. `mysql_fetch_array` returns the next row of results from the resource, or `false` if there are no more rows. The `@` prefix suppresses any errors that PHP might display if there's an error in calling the function.
3. `$ligne` is a variable that the row is assigned to. The row is represented as an array.
4. `expression1 != expression2` compares the two expressions. If they're not equal, then the comparison succeeds, and `if` performs the statements in the body. In this case, `expression1` is `false`, and `expression2` is the assignment. So it compares the value assigned to the variable with `false`. In other words, if a row was fetched, the `$er` assignment will be performed.

Answer (score 3):

1. `$resultat` is a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). See [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) manual.
2. This has two parts:

   - `@` is [error suppression operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Any errors generated by the following `mysql_fetch_array` are ignored.
   - [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns one row of the query result as array.
3. `$ligne` is a regular variable, nothing special. It is assigned the array returned from `mysql_fetch_array`.
4. `false != (some expression)` is the same as `(some expression) != false`. [`!=`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) tests that the value is not false after [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). What might confuse you is that `(some expression)` is [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) it this case. Value of an assignment is the value being assigned.

Few more remarks:

- You probably want `false !== …` instead of `false !=`, this ensures that `mysql_fetch_array` really returned `false` and not an empty array (which should not happen, but who knows). `!==` is evaluated without type juggling.
- `if (false != (expression)) { … }` is equivalent to `if (expression) { … }`.
- Your code uses an outdated, deprecated API ([`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)) to access MySQL database from PHP. Two other APIs ([`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) are available as a replacement, `mysqli` being the one designed to be mostly “compatible” (read “looking the same”) with the old `mysql`.

Answer (score 2):

> (1) The variable $resultat is an array of elements returned from the
>   query output. If the query has nothing to return then $resultat will
>   be an array with 0 elements?

No, it contains a reference to the result of the query.

> (2) @mysql_fetch_array returns each row of $resultat. Is this correct?

It will return the next line of the query, as an array. Here it's called once, so it will return the first line. And using the @ is not a good practice.

> (3) I am lost after this ... is $ligne a special kind of variable that
>   holds all output of @mysql_fetch_array?

Assigning a variable also returns the assigned value. Here it's like calling `$ligne = @mysql_fetch_array($resultat)`, and then check if $value != false.

> (4) How does false!= work?

`false != $foo` is equivalent to `$foo != false` (but less intuitive).

Answer (score 2):

1. `$resultat` is an object that contains a mysql result set, which is like an array, but not.
2. `@` is used to supress warning messages about mysql_query.  `@` is most likely placed there because `mysql_query` is not recommended.   `mysql_fetch_array` returns one row from the result set.

`if (false != ($ligne = @mysql_fetch_array ($resultat))) {`
The return value from `mysql_fetch_array` is assigned to the variable `$ligne`.  The `if(fales !=` is checking if the assignment of `$linge` is truthy, e.g. not null.

I have written your code block in a cleaner manner.

```
<?php
  $er = '';
  $resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE username ='".$username."'");

  while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array ($resultat) ) {
    $er.='This username ('.$username.') is already taken.';
  }
```

Comment: This will write that `$username` is taken for each possibly more that once, as `temp_users.username` may not be unique key.

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE username ='".$username."'");

//This queries the database to see if the username the user entered exists already

if (false != ($ligne = @mysql_fetch_array ($resultat))) {

//the if statement checks to see if the statement doesn't equal false. Essentially, it checks if the statement is true. I don't know what $ligne is, we need more information. It seems like an empty variable designed to hold the results.

    $er.='This username ('.$username.') is already taken.';

//This appends 'This username ('.$username.') is already taken.' to the variable $er
}
```

I hope that this helps!